# .html work, but text not appear after ajax request

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

After ajax call, I'm appending div `buf` to some message box, but text appears after the dialog is reopened. On Chrome, firefox, IE 8, this works fine, but not in ie 7.

Edited: 
I have dialog window wich open on clicking a link. Then i do ajax request and get a message. This message should appear in dialog window (in some div) after clicking a button in the dialog. But in IE7 message appears after dialog window is reopened.

```
$("#promised_pay_dialog").dialog({
        buttons: {
            "some button": function(){
                if ($('#confirm').is(':checked')) {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: 'ajax/promisedPayment',
                        type: "POST",
                        data: {
                            subsId:$("#sid").val()
                        },
                        success: function(buf){
                            $('#message_box').html(buf);
                            return false;
                        }
                    });
                }
                else {
                    alert("some message");
                }
            },
            "some button": function() {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        },
        show: {
            effect: "blind",
            duration: 1000
        },
        hide: {
            effect: "explode",
            duration: 1000
        },
        modal: true,
        resizable: false,
        width: 550,
        height: 250
    });
```

solved the problem, but **not** satisfactorily:

On clicking the link, call function `createDialog("")` with no argument. After ajax request, receive message and call `createDialog(buf)`. But i think it's no good solution. Any ideas?

```
function createDialog(mess){
    $('#message_box').html(mess);
    $("#promised_pay_dialog").dialog({
        buttons: {
            "some button": function(){
                if ($('#confirm').is(':checked')) {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: 'ajax/promisedPayment',
                        type: "POST",
                        data: {
                            subsId:$("#sid").val()
                        },
                        cache:false,
                        success: function(buf){
                            createDialog(buf);
                        }
                    });
                }
                else {
                    alert("some message");
                }
            },
            "some button": function() {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        },
        show: {
            effect: "blind",
            duration: 1000
        },
        hide: {
            effect: "blind",
            duration: 1000
        },
        modal: true,
        resizable: false,
        width: 550,
        height: 250
    });
}
```

Comment: Please improve the text, it's impossible to understand.

Comment: maybe something to do with jquery version? I know some support for older versions was dropped in 2.0

Comment: I have dialog window wich open on "a href" click. Than i do ajax request and get message. This message should appear in dialog window (in some div) after click button in dialog. But message appear after dialog window reopened in IE7.

Comment: try jQuery 1.7.x I have found it to be the most stable version yet. Especially regarding IE versions

Comment: it's like your dialog is not getting refreshed...remove all the effects and try again...

Comment: jquery 1.7.2 same problem. Removed all effects - same problem.

Comment: Please check if by putting a dummy `alert` or `console.log` after `$('#message_box').html(buf);` works or not. I faced a similar problem long back and inserting a dummy statement to delay things worked. Of course reason is still unknown to me!

Answer (score 0):

`.html()` is knows for issues with IE6-8

Try replacing the following

```
$('#message_box').html(buf);
```

with

```
$('#message_box').empty().html(buf);
```